# Cannot call method 'id' of undefined

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

My world.js looks like this:

```
var protractor = require('protractor');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer('xxxxx').
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).build();

driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(100000);


module.exports.World = function World(callback) {
    this.browser = protractor.wrapDriver(driver);
    this.by = protractor.by;
    callback();
};
```

then in steps.js:

```
{
     element(by.id('username')).sendKeys("admin");
}
```

When I ran it using cucumber.js, the error is:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'id' of undefined

but if I remove world.js and run it using protractor, it works.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not exporting `by` globally. I'm not sure why you're able to use the `element` function at all - but in any case, you should probably be doing something like:

```
module.exports.World = function World(callback) {
    global.browser = protractor.wrapDriver(driver);
    global.by = protractor.by; 
};
```